# List Active Channels in Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I can watch several files for changes delivered by webhook. If I lose the list of channels created (per file watched), how can I get a list of existing / active channel ids, so that I can cancel them when I'm done with them?

**Feature Request:** https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173730342 Please +1 / comment to encourage google to provide this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API method to list the channels. You should keep the information identifying the channel, which is returned when [creating the channel](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#creating-notification-channels) and when receiving the [corresponding notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#receiving-notifications).

#### File a Feature Request:

I can't see any Feature Request regarding this in the [Drive component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106) in Issue Tracker, so I'd suggest you to file one.

#### Update - Feature Request filed:

- [Feature Request: List Active Channels](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173730342)

#### Reference:

- [Channels](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/channels)
- [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push)

Comment: keeping the information cannot be guaranteed because there may be a network or persistence failure when the API call returns. but yes to the extent this doesn't happen I will save the information carefully. Unfortunate that Google missed this elementary principle of API design, but maybe a feature request will help.

Comment: Feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173730342

Comment: @user2297550 Thank you for filing this feature request. I added it to my answer in order to give it more visibility.